# How to embed arbitrary dynamic HTML String into Haskell's Lucid Html type?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lucid

How can I parse an html string for example `<p>Test</p>` and have this be converted to value that would be similar to `p_ "Test"`?

So the function type would be `String -> Html ()`.

I've found the following project https://github.com/dbaynard/lucid-from-html but this generates actual Haskell source code as a `String`.

I'm aware that there are HTML parsing libraries, but I'm just wondering if there already exists a library that has implemented this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lucid-2.9.11/docs/Lucid-Base.html#v:toHtmlRaw

```
toHtmlRaw "<p>Test</p>"
```

The above seems to work well enough, though possibly it does not check for valid syntax.

Comment: +1.   Note that the value of `p_ "Test"` is basically a complicated monadic representation of the byte string `<p>Test</p>`, so its actually already rendered HTML rather than any sort of DOM.  As such, you don't really gain anything by parsing the HTML and then re-rendering it to `Html ()` -- it'll be a sort of expensive identity function.  If you need to validate or normalize some HTML before rendering, you'd *still* be better off using a completely separate library (maybe HXT?) to parse and re-render it, and then use Lucid's `toHtmlRaw` on your re-rendered HTML.